# getting an installable package from an Applicaton in linux

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, linaro

I don't know is this possible or not, so here's the question:

I have ALSA Installed on my system  and I do not have the installation files and dependencies of it, now I want to copy this ALSA into another system with the same Hardware, so how can I get an Installable package (or something like that) of ALSA and all of it's dependencies?
the hardware is cubieboard1 and both have linaro, but the kernels versions are diffrent (3.0.57 is mine,and the 3.4.67 is the other)

Comment: Use your distro's package manager.

Comment: tnx for reply, can you please tell me some details? I'm not an expert in linux, how can I get the sources from package manager?